# What parts of Bitcoin (litecoin etc) are Little Endian?

Tags: development, blockchain-fork, performance

As mentioned on this [Hardfork Wishlist](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hardfork_Wishlist), many developers want Bitcoin to be entirely Big Endian for consistency and performance reasons.

I'm looking for a concise list of all the areas that Bitcoin uses data in Little (or Big) Endian format so I can create an "endian coin" just for the purposes of testing capacity and performance.

Answer (score 2):

All numeric values on the wire are little-endian with the exception of network addresses and ports, which are big-endian.  This includes Sha-256 digests which are treated as 32-byte numbers.  It does not include data pushed on to the script stack, however, which is copied as-is from the script element.

The regular numbers aren't really a problem since you end up shifting the bytes to form the internal numeric value in either case.  But the 32-byte values are expensive since you end up allocating a new byte array to reverse the bytes as you go to/from the wire protocol byte stream.